# Почему import PMKFoundation выдает ошибку No such module 'PMKFoundation'? (Pod установлен корректно)

Tags: swift, promise, cocoapods

Делаю как написано в инструкции (https://github.com/PromiseKit/Foundation)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все успешно установлено, но в Xcode получаю ошибку при  импорте PMKFoundation. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с другими установленными pods таких проблем нет. Переустанавливала и пробовала указывать import PromiseKit.PMKFoundation - не работает. 
Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

PMKFoundation уже входит в PromiseKit. Попробуйте так:

```
В Podfile файле: pod 'PromiseKit'
В swift файле: import PromiseKit.PMKFoundation
```